# AJAX request is successful but return nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, openweathermap

I was trying to make a weather app by using open weather API so when I was request through ajax, the request is successful but its returning nothing. please point out my mistake.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit-weather').click(function () {
        var city = $('#city').val();
        if (city != "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + '&units=metric' + '&APPID=**********',
                type: "GET",
                datatype: "jsonp",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#error').html('Let first write city name');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I would highly recommend not sharing your API key publically.

Comment: can you try removing datatype: "jsonp" from the request and then try

Comment: on console the data the output is `blank` or `undefined`?

Comment: @aashir khan Sir please check Your Link first in address bar what its return there check it please.

Comment: i think its return error when you used above url

Comment: @Jana its return nothing

Comment: @ Jeff Hechler thanks for inform next time I'll worried about it

Comment: You definitely get a "200 OK" status from the server (check the relevant request line in your browser's network tab in the developer tools)? And if you click on that request and view the response body, it is empty? Are you definitely submitted a valid value for "city"? I'm pretty sure you should set `dataType: "json"` not "jsonp"

Comment: @ Jaykumar Gondaliya check it here https://jsfiddle.net/AashirKhan/7gxnr7cb/1/

Comment: @ADyson i follow your suggestion still its not working https://jsfiddle.net/AashirKhan/7gxnr7cb/1/

Comment: If you use HTTP (http://jsfiddle.net/AashirKhan/7gxnr7cb/1/) the fiddle works perfectly as far as I can see. If you use HTTPS it's blocked because you can't go from HTTPS to HTTP (which your ajax call uses) when using ajax - that error appears in the console. As soon as you load the site over HTTP it's fine. If you were looking at your browser console you'd have seen that error immediately, and realise that the call was not "successful" at all, in fact it never even happened. Do you actually understand how to use your developer tools to debug?

Comment: @ADyson no I'm a beginner please help how to fix it.

Comment: I already fixed it for you - you can't have a website using https and an ajax call within it using http. It's disallowed for security reasons. Use the http version of JSFiddle, or use the https version of the API, if that exists. And read a tutorial on how to use the developer tools in your browser (console and network tabs are the most important when debugging ajax)

Comment: when you take the api from openweathermap so it is not secure. This problem is not your site but your api site so please check how to take the parfect API from openweathermap website.

Comment: And please don't share your API key. Because any person use or hack.

Comment: Because i check all the way but problem is in this APi site of "openweathermap".

Comment: @ Er CEO Vora Mayur i see

Comment: hello aashir, your code not try in any HTTPS website because your API is HTTP so try or execute your code in HTTP website .

Comment: run code successfully get the data in this link check, http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Put your code here and execute (http://jsfiddle.net/). If site open in HTTPS so remove "S"  and try in HTTP

Comment: @Er CEO Vora Mayur error occur please check it http://jsfiddle.net/AashirKhan/7gxnr7cb/1/

Answer (score 0):

load jsfiddle with http instead of https, it will work

its because you probably have a free account and api don't support secure request on free. and your web has a secure connection so it blocked the request.
try  http on your website 
Check your network tab in console.

```
<!-- your code is fine-->
```

try this first  [https](https://jsfiddle.net/uxcv0a7d/)

try this then [http](http://jsfiddle.net/uxcv0a7d/)

Comment: sorry,honestly  i did not saw that,